# Convert html title to rtl format

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image: Image showing the text in rtl and title normally]

I was able to apply rtl to all the content in my html pages. But title tags are still coming normally

How can we apply any class to title or tooltips ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the title with  Unicode RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE character `&#x202E;` See http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/

Eg.

`<a href="#" title="&#x202E; My text" />Test</a>`

Depending on your use case I would suggest doing it through javascript/jQuery(may be for particular locale only) for all title tags in a page.